# Как определить бездействие пользователя в windows

Tags: c++, windows

Как на C++ определить используется ли компьютер в настоящее время?

Через GetLastInputInfo() получаю время последних действий пользователя и определяю время бездействия. Этот вариант не работает, если пользователь смотрит видео.

Каким способом более точно определить отсутствие активности?

Comment: Можно предложить совсем "дубовый" метод: делать скрин раз в секунду, например. Если с прошлым одинаково, то время простоя увеличивается на 1 секунду.

Answer (score 2):

Вроде как это можно сделать посредством API Планировщика заданий, через [интерфейс `IIdleTrigger`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa380724(v=vs.85).aspx). см [Task Idle Conditions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa383561(v=vs.85).aspx).

Answer (score 2):

Вот вам пример с использованием Планировщика задач версии 2 (Windows Vista и выше).

Так как нам придётся работать с COM, то необходимо сделать три вещи:

1. В свойствах проекта перейти к параметру *Configuration Properties -> Linker -> Input -> Additional Dependencies* и обеспечить наличие там библиотек `ole32.lib` и `uuid.lib`, отделённых друг от друга и от имеющегося содержимого строки точками с запятой (`;`). Вот пример того, как вообще выглядит данный параметр:

   [image: введите сюда описание изображения]
2. Добавить в код вспомогательную функцию, выполняющую безопасное приведение типов указателей и избегающую, в отличие от `reinterpret_cast`, неопределённого поведения (а именно нарушения strict aliaing rule — см. статью «[Про C++ алиасинг, ловкие оптимизации и подлые баги](https://habrahabr.ru/post/114117/)»):

   ```
   #include <cstring>
   #include <type_traits>
   #if __cplusplus < 201103L
   #   define static_assert(cond, text)
   #endif

   template<
       class D, class S,
       class = std::enable_if<std::is_pointer<S>::value && std::is_pointer<S>::value>::type
   >
   static D convert(S in)
   {
       D out;
       static_assert(sizeof(in) == sizeof(out), "incompatible pointer types");
       memcpy(&out, &in, sizeof(in));
       return out;
   }
   ```
3. В начале работы программы вызвать `CoInitialize()`, а в конце — `CoUninitialize()`.

Теперь перейдём к непосредственно регистрации обработчика. Сразу отмечу два момента:

1. Пользователь имеет доступ к оснастке управления Планировщиком, а потому может отключить наш обработчик. Не надо этому противодействовать — пусть владелец компьютера сам решает, что ему нужно, а что нет.
2. В качестве обработчика задачи можно назначить только исполняемый файл. Поэтому нам потребуется написать небольшую утилиту, которая будет посылать уведомление всем запущенным экземплярам вашей программы. Это можно сделать, например, с помощью именованных оконных сообщений:

   ```
   #include <windows.h>

   int main()
   {
       // Вместо "mymsg" подставьте своё название, например, "имя-программы.on_idle" 
       const UINT uMsgId = RegisterWindowMessage(TEXT("mymsg"));
       SendMessage(HWND_BROADCAST, uMsgId, 0, 0);
       return 0;
   }
   ```

   Ваша же программа, в свою очередь, должна будет отлавливать это сообщение:

   ```
   // Где-нибудь во время создания окна инициализируйте эту переменную вызовом 
   // uMsgId = RegisterWindowMessage(TEXT("название-указанное-выше"));
   INT uIdleNotificationMsgId;

   // Обработчик оконных сообщений
   LRESULT CALLBACK WindowProc(
       HWND   hwnd,
       UINT   uMsg,
       WPARAM wParam,
       LPARAM lParam
   )
   {
       switch(uMsg)
       {
           // Здесь вы обрабатываете все обычные оконные сообщения

           default:
               if(uMsg == uIdleNotificationMsgId)
               {
                   // Обнаружено бездействие. Выполняете всё, что хотели

                   return 0;
               }
               else
                   return DefWindowProc(hwnd, uMsg, wParam, lParam);
       }
   }
   ```

Теперь приступим непосредственно к регистрации обработчика:

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <mstask.h>
#include <objidl.h>

// ...

ITaskScheduler *scheduler;
const HRESULT lComStartupResult = CoCreateInstance(
    /* rclsid       */ CLSID_CTaskScheduler, // Класс планировщика задач
    /* pUnkOuter    */ NULL,
    /* dwClsContext */ CLSCTX_INPROC_SERVER, // Загружаем mstask.dll в наш процесс
    /* riid         */ IID_ITaskScheduler,   // Нас интересует конкретный интерфейс
    /* ppv          */ convert<void**>(&scheduler)
);
if(SUCCEEDED(lComStartupResult))
{
    // Создаём задачу, выполняемую при бездействии
    LPCWSTR pwszTaskName;
    ITask *task;
    const HRESULT lTaskAdditionResult = scheduler->NewWorkItem(
        /* pwszTaskName */ L"MyTask",   // Подставьте сюда осмысленное имя задачи
        /* rclsid       */ CLSID_CTask,
        /* riid         */ IID_ITask,
        /* ppunk        */ convert<void**>(&task)
    );
    if(SUCCEEDED(lTaskAdditionResult))
    {
        // Указываем, что задача должна исполняться сразу же при обнаружении простоя.
        // В каждой версии Windows свои критерии наступления этого события:
        //
        // * Windows Vista ждёт десять минут с момента прекращения пользования
        //   клавиатурой и мышью.
        // * Windows 7 и выше ждёт уже четыре минуты.
        TASK_TRIGGER triggerInfo;
        memset(&triggerInfo, 0, sizeof(triggerInfo));
        rTrigger.cbTriggerSize = sizeof(triggerInfo);
        rTrigger.TriggerType = TASK_EVENT_TRIGGER_ON_IDLE;

        // Создаём триггер с указанными параметрами
        WORD triggerId; // Параметр помечен как [out], поэтому инициализация не требуется
        ITaskTrigger *trigger;
        const HRESULT lTriggerAdditionResult = pITask->CreateTrigger(
            /* piNewTrigger */ &triggerId,
            /* ppTrigger    */ &trigger
        );
        if(SUCCEEDED(lTriggerAdditionResult))
        {
            trigger->SetTrigger(&triggerInfo);

            // Указываем программу, которая будет запущена при бездействии. Она, в свою
            // очередь, должна будет послать вам уведомление (как именно - см. выше)
            // и завершиться
            trigger->SetProgram(L"путь до программы");
            trigger->SetComment(L"описание задачи для администратора, что и зачем делает");

            // Сохраняем задачу в Планировщик задач
            IPersistFile *saver;
            const HRESULT lSaverRetrieved = trigger->QueryInterface(
                /* riid      */ IID_IPersistFile, 
                /* ppvObject */ convert<void**>(&saver)
            );
            if(SUCCEEDED(lSaverRetrieved))
            {
                saver->Save(/* pszFileName */ NULL, /* fRemember */ FALSE);
                saver->Release();
            }

            trigger->Release();
        }
        else
        {
            // Ошибка при добавлении триггера
        }

        task->Release();
    }
    else
    {
        // Ошибка при создании задачи
    }

    scheduler->Release();
```

Comment: Работа с Планировщиком заданий не требует прав администратора.

Comment: @VTT, ваша правда. Исправил.

Answer (score 2):

Некоторые приложения, особенно для просмотра видео и игр, устанавливают в системе флаг `SPI_SCREENSAVERRUNNING`. Делается это для того, чтобы система не включала скринсейвер и вообще считала, что она используется - даже при отсутствии пользовательского ввода.
Получить значение этого флага можно с помощью функции [SystemParametersInfo()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724947%28v=vs.85%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396).
Также, можно "ловить" момент его изменения, обрабатывая сообщение [WM_SETTINGCHANGE](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/windows/desktop/ms725497%28v=vs.85%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396).
К сожалению, не очень легко отличить момент выполнения такой программы от момента, когда система действительно простаивает со включенным скринсейвером.

Я бы предложил такой вариант:

- получаем значение таймаута экранной заставки, флагом `SPI_GETSCREENSAVETIMEOUT` (возможно, понадобится ещё обрабатывать
  сообщение `WM_SETTINGCHANGE`, чтобы корректно обрабатывать изменение таймаута заставки)
- засекаем последний момент времени, когда был пользовательский ввод ([GetLastInputInfo()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/windows/desktop/ms646302(v=vs.85).aspx))
- получаем значение флага `SPI_GETSCREENSAVERRUNNING`
- на основании текущего времени вычисляем количество секунд, прошедших с момента последнего пользовательского ввода
- определяем результат

  - если прошедшее время меньше таймаута заставки, а флаг `SPI_GETSCREENSAVERRUNNING` установлен, то пользователь смотрит видео или во что-то играет (возможно, сейчас смотрит какой-то внутриигровой ролик)
  - если прошедшее время меньше таймаута заставки, а флаг `SPI_GETSCREENSAVERRUNNING` не установлен, то вероятней всего, это момент простоя системы
  - если прошедшее время больше таймаута заставки, то результат неопределённый: либо используем предыдущие результаты, либо интерпретируем согласно своим интересам :)

И не забыть отдельно обрабатывать вариант, когда экранная заставка отключена в настройках (приложениям это не мешает установить флаг `SPI_SCREENSAVERRUNNING`)